# Passing variables from flash(action script 3.0) to php

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I know theres lots of topics about this but no matter what i do i just CANT get it to work, at all. so i want to pass a variable that was defined in flash over to php and, with some php magic, do things with that variable. for now im trying to put the variable "username" into my table. heres what ive got so far:

In flash ive got:

```
connect();

function connect(){
var urlString:String = "http://[webhost]/check.php"; 

function Submit():void
{
    var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    requestVars.username= 10; // Dummy data to be sent to php

    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    urlRequest.url = urlString;
    urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    urlRequest.data = requestVars;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);

sendToURL(urlRequest)

    try { loader.load(urlRequest); }

    catch (error:Error) { // Handle Immediate Errors 

    }
}
}

function loaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void
{
    trace(e.target.data); // Response Text
}
```

and heres my php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
    $username=$_POST["username"];
}
     else if(empty($username)){
    $username="Unknown";

}
    if (!($link=mysql_connect('localhost','[user]','[pass]'))) 
       { 
          echo "Error Connecting To Database."; 
          exit(); 
       } 
       if (!mysql_select_db('[table name]',$link)) 
       { 
          echo "Error Selecting Database."; 
          exit(); 
       }
       try
       {
           mysql_query("insert into test(user)  values('$username')",$link);                
           print "done=true";          
       }
       catch(Exception $e)
       {
           print "done=$e->getMessage()";          
       }
       echo "done=true";    
?>
```

thanks ~ElementalVenom

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the urlRequest.method to URLRequestMethod.GET, it will get passed to PHP in the global $_GET array, not in the $_POST array as you are doing in your PHP. When the URLRequest's method is "GET", it simply adds the url-encodes the parameters and appends it to the end of the URL so the end result is http://example.com/check.php?username=10.

To quote the docs on URLRequest's data property (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data):

> This property is used in conjunction with the method property. When the value of method is >GET, the value of data is appended to the value of URLRequest.url, using HTTP query-string >syntax. When the method value is POST (or any value other than GET), the value of data is >transmitted in the body of the HTTP request.

Thus, simply changing

```
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
```

to

```
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

should do the trick.

OR, change your PHP to use $_GET like so:

```
if(!empty($_GET['username'])){
$username=$_GET["username"];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Alright, I won't be able to try it tell tomaro but it sounds right. Thanks!

Comment: This still does not work, im  pressing F12 in flash for the program preview. Would that have anything to do with it? like do i need to actual publish it then run the swf?

Comment: That might be your problem. From the docs on URLLoader: "By default, the calling SWF file and the URL you load must be in exactly the same domain. For example, a SWF file at www.adobe.com can load data only from sources that are also at www.adobe.com. To load data from a different domain, place a URL policy file on the server hosting the data." So you may need to publish the SWF and run it on the same domain as the PHP file.

Comment: I just tried that and it turns out that it still wont work, anything else that i need to do?